# Can not properly bind observableArray of observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have the following code which should bind observableArray of observables.

```
<button data-bind="click: loadTag">Upload</button>
<span data-bind="foreach: langs">
    <input data-bind="value: $data, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
</span>

<div data-bind = "text: ko.toJS(langs)">

function vm() {
    var self = this;
    this.langs      = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.initiate = function(){
        self.langs = ko.observableArray([]);
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            self.langs.push(ko.observable('start'));
        }
    }
    this.initiate();

    this.loadTag = function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            self.langs()[i](i);
        }
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

JS fiddle is [available](http://jsfiddle.net/e9M47/).

As you see in the beginning it binds correctly and also binding works when it loadTag. But the problem is that when I modify elements in input, binding does not propagate. I think that I miss something really simple, but can not find what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you directly have `ko.observable` objects in your array you need to use `$rawData` instead of `$data` to bind directly to the observable objects themselves and not to their values:

```
<span data-bind="foreach: langs">
    <input data-bind="value: $rawData, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
</span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fC2gJ/).

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> **`$rawData`**
>
> This is the raw view model value in the current context. Usually this
>   will be the same as `$data`, but if the view model provided to Knockout
>   is wrapped in an observable, `$data` will be the unwrapped view model,
>   and `$rawData` will be the observable itself.

Comment: Wow, did not know that. Even haven't heard about it. Thanks.

Comment: This is a newly added feature in KO 3.0. Prior to that you had to it was not really supported to directly have observables inside an observablearray.